# Ubuntu 21.04 on iMac 19,2 Model - No Sound Output

Tags: sound, alsa, mac

I'm really confused as to why no sound is coming out of the speakers or headphones.  Ubuntu seems to recognize all of the devices just fine.  From the attached images you can see the audio meter is moving while I'm playing music.  I've included the settings screen and the alsamixer output.  I can't seem to find anything online to even really troubleshoot this.  Any troubleshooting suggestions would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

When I use sudo dmesg | grep -i sound", here is the result I get:

[   21.484127] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input7
[   21.484185] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input8
[   21.484226] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input9
[   21.484257] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input10
[   21.484279] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[   21.484319] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the output of `dmesg | grep -i sound` so we can start to diagnose your problem.

Comment: thanks, I edited it above

Comment: "lspci | grep -i audio" provides the following:
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]

Comment: OK so the Cannon Lake is just the name of the integrated chip/card that Intel make specially for Mac. I don't know if ubuntu has the firmware in place, sorry. You can try and search for linux firmware for Cannon Lake or maybe just update your firmware `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware` and let us know your progress.

Comment: From my research, it looks like this will be fixed in a newer kernel.  This web site gives me some clue (https://h-node.org/soundcards/view/en/2157/Intel-Corporation-Cannon-Lake-PCH-cAVS--rev-10-/1/1/undef/undef/undef/undef/sound-card-works/undef).  Other sites have indicated issues with the iMac 19,2 sound card.

Comment: If you are in the know (I am definitely NOT) then you can extract the firmware from your Mac if you are still dual booting. Here is an example of people that have done this for other firmware & drivers https://packages.aunali1.com/apple/wifi-fw/18G2022/ so you could search within that community.